# Strange JQuery is not defined error

Tags: jquery, html

http://www.maro-z.com/examples/jquery.gantt/

I was trying out this JQuery Gantt chart plugin and I'm encountering a peculiar problem.

**sample.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.gantt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.gantt.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function(){
    $("#gantt01").gantt({
    'type': 'month',
    'range': 50,
    'titles': ['Name', 'Type']
    });

    $('#gantt01').addTask({
    'titles': ['Layout Mapping','Planned'],
    'start_date': '20130731',
    'end_date': '20140813',
    'color': '#0000FF',
    });

    $('#gantt01').addTask({
    'titles': ['','Actual'],
    'start_date': '20130931',
    'end_date': '20141013',
    'color': '#FF00FF',
    });

});
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gantt01"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in /var/www/test/ I have sample.php, jquery.js, jquery.gantt.js,jquery.gantt.css and the images folder (which jquery.gantt.css uses). This works perfectly.
Now to make things more organized, this is what I attempted:

**gantt.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gantt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.gantt.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function(){
    $("#gantt01").gantt({
    'type': 'month',
    'range': 50,
    'titles': ['Name', 'Type']
    });

    $('#gantt01').addTask({
    'titles': ['Layout Mapping','Planned'],
    'start_date': '20130731',
    'end_date': '20140813',
    'color': '#0000FF',
    });

    $('#gantt01').addTask({
    'titles': ['','Actual'],
    'start_date': '20130931',
    'end_date': '20141013',
    'color': '#FF00FF',
    });

});
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gantt01"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is the placement of the js, css and image files. I moved the js files into `js/`, css into `css/` and images into `img/`. And I changed the references to the images in `jquery.gantt.css` to `../img/` instead of `images/` as it was earlier.

But this refuses to work. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in Chrome dev tools in the jquery.gantt.js file. But I'm able to access all the required js, css files via the dev tools.

Any clue what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Change your order if files  in **gantt.php**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gantt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.gantt.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gantt.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.gantt.css" />
```

you are loding `gantt.js`  before  `jquery.js`

Comment: Yeah I realized this right after I posted this. Feel silly. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: you are welcome.No issues ..happens to every programmer.Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You changed the order of the scripts.

First include jQuery, then plugins, then your own code.

If your files are indeed in the correct folders as referenced here, it should work.